# react-native map customized css or style

Tags: javascript, react-native, maps

Is there a way to customize a MapView like you can with regular javascript?  I'd like to do a theme like this: file:///Users/robertkelly/Downloads/snazzy-maps-example-ultra-light-with-labels-style.html

and I'm able to get it working in vanilla javascript: http://jsbin.com/fodapo/edit?js,output

but can't seem to figure out how to implement this in React-Native since there is no standard google maps api to give input to the mapview like:

```
[{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e9e9e9"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":17}]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a method to style the RN build-in [MapView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/mapview.html) yet, but I think the possibility to define a custom map style would be a nice feature and should maybe added to the [react native productpains](https://productpains.com/product/react-native/?tab=top).

Meanwhile you should have a look at the [react-native-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl) component (android/ios). You can [add a custom map style](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/API.md#custom-styles) to `react-native-mapbox-gl` created using Mapbox Studio ([examples](https://www.mapbox.com/gallery/)).

Comment: I ended up settling on that, thanks for the recommendation